# Visual Studio App Center Error: Publishing build artifacts failed with an error: Not found PathtoPublish

Tags: visual-studio-app-center

I'm using Visual Studio App center for continuous integration of react native application.

When I run build, it's showing build successful in log. But the status is showing as failed.

I'm getting below error. How can I fix this ?

```
[error]Publishing build artifacts failed with an error: Not found PathtoPublish: /Users/vsts/agent/2.126.0/work/1/a/build
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am also getting the same error. Did you find something?

Comment: I solved it by generating universal apk

Comment: i also got the same solution :p

Comment: You saved my day. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved it by generating universal apk.